# How do I get a property from an EntityManagerFactory in my JUnit test?

Tags: spring, hibernate, properties, junit, entitymanager

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, JUnit 4.8.1, and Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I have this defined in my test application context:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.myco.subco,com.parentco.fdr.myproject" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>
```

How do I get the "packagesToScan" property as a string in my JUnit test?  I tried

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
public class SerializableTest extends AbstractNTsubcoTests
{

        @Autowired
        private EntityManagerFactory m_entityManagerFactory;

    @Test
    public final void testSerializable()
    {
        final String packagesToScan = (String) m_entityManagerFactory.getProperties().get("packagesToScan");
        System.out.println("packagesToScan:" + packagesToScan);
    }   // testSerializable
}
```

however, the above prints out "null," despite the fact I have defined in a non-null value in the context.

Answer (score 0):

The property is set to the org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, not the EntityManagerFactory. The LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is not an EntityManagerFactory, it creates the EntityManagerFactory.

After looking at Spring code, the packagesToScan property is set in the DefaultPersistenceUnitManager and you can't get its value.

I think you could define a Spring property with a default and query that property instead.

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="${packagesToScan:org.myco.subco,com.parentco.fdr.myproject}" />
```

Here's how to get it

```
@Value("${packagesToScan}")
private String packagesToScan;
```